# How to remove the external css from wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

How to remove external css (maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/) from wordpress code?

I used "remove_action('wp_head', 'ut-fontawesome-css'). But it's not working.

Comment: can you tell where you placed the `remove_action` function and what theme are you using?

Comment: I added inside  the function.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) takes a function name as second argument to remove/unhook, and also the priority as third argument. In PHP a function cannot have a hyphen it its name. `'ut-fontawesome-css'` looks like it is a style handle. Styles are added with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/)  and removed with [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/). Without looking at your parent theme code I would assume that what you should do is to dequeue this style using something like below

```
function remove_font_awesome() {
  wp_dequeue_style('ut-fontawesome-css');
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_font_awesome', 100);
```

Please note, that I only assumed that `ut-fontawesome-css` is a correct handle to use here and i used priority as high as 100 just to 'try' to dequeue the style after it has been enqueued. A better approach would be for you to search the parent theme for where the style is being enqueued and either unhook the function if it is only enqueuing the font awesome, or hook in a function as above that would dequeue the style.

Comment: <link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css' href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.3.9' type='text/css' media='all' />, I want to remove this. Even I have mention the same code which you have wrote above.